# Максимальное количество строк в функции

Tags: php, стандарт

Есть ли стандарты или рекомендации, относительно максимального количества строк в одной функции PHP?
Есть ли разница в контексте производительности, когда в одной функции 100 строк, или эти строки разбиты на две функции по 50 строк?

Comment: Ну как бы одна функция = одно действие. Если действий более одного - разбить на две. И т.д.

Comment: В NetBeans IDE есть рекомендация делать функцию не более 20 строк и класс не более 200.

Comment: класс не более 200? как Вы думаете, на чем основываются такие рекомендации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Себе можно сколько угодно правил придумать, но главные, которые следует соблюдать это [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) и [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). Они устанавливают общие принципы написания кода - синтаксиса, именования, оформления (в которые входят и пробелы, и отступы, и скобки со строками).

> Есть ли стандарты или рекомендации, относительно максимального
>   количества строк в одной функции PHP?

Нет ограничения на кол-во строк, есть "мягкое" ограничение на длину строки (120 символов, рекомендовано - 80), то есть, предельно допустимые условные значения.

> Есть ли разница в контексте производительности, когда в одной функции
>   100 строк, или эти строки разбиты на две функции по 50 строк?

Всё зависит от того, что ваши строки делают. Если вы 100 раз выводите слово то проще это циклом делать в 3 строки, не так ли? Делите сложные процессы на единичные задачи и собирайте их в главной функции/методе и не будет у вас 100 строк никогда. Не маловажная часть - ваш сервер. Если до сих пор стоит apache2 и по минуте ждёте загрузки сложных страниц, стоит задуматься над оптимизацией серверной части (аля "hello", php-fpm) и самого кода.

*PS: Надеюсь, помог вам с поисками ответов. А PSR стандарты вы прочтите и старайтесь писать с их применением*